# Why is my web service trying to redirect to a URL that does not exist?

Tags: python, django, backend

Basically, I have a web service that I am trying to build using Django. While working on the user LogIn, I ran into a confusing error. If the user is None (in my code, this means that the password or username does not match an existing one), then the user should be redirected to the LogIn page again, which has a URL path of

```
/accounts/login,
```

however, is instead sent to

```
/accounts/login/login
```

This is the code that controls the user LogIn

```
def logIn(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)


        if username is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return redirect('/accounts/register/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'logIn.html')
```

This is the URLs file inside the app

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Empty),
    path('register/', views.register),
    path('login/', views.logIn)
]
```

and this is the main URLs file in the project

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('ControlApp.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('Accounts.urls'))
]
```

[Here's the full code in case it helps](https://github.com/AlcalinoGitHub/DjangoExperiment)

I tried changing removing completely the redirect instruction from the logIn function, however, even then the user was getting redirected to

```
/accounts/login/login
```

I assume there is a problem in another part of the code that I am missing, which is why the full code is available for inspection

It would be of great help is anyone here could help me, since this is the first time I try to build something like this, and I am pretty much learning stuff as I need it

Comment: I think your problem in in the html: login.html. <form action = 'login' method = 'post'> try to remove action = 'login' cuz django is already handling that

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a look at your code.
That's not the redirect problem.

That's because of submit url of the login form.
You should change the code like below.

```js
<form action = '/accounts/login' method = 'post'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
  <input type = 'submit'>
</form>
```

In addition, When check the authentication, you should check user, not username.

```js
if user is not None:
    auth.login(request, user)
    return redirect('/')
else:
    return redirect('/accounts/register/')
```